# Subspace of Polish space is Polish

Tags: general-topology, polish-spaces

Let $X$ be a Polish space. We know that $A\subset X$ is Polish iff it is a $G_\delta$ subset.  So, since every open and every closed subset is $G_\delta$, it is in particular Polish.

Now, we let $A\subset X$ be an open subset and obtained two Polish spaces $A$ and $X\setminus A$.  My question is as follows: If $B\subset X\setminus A$ open, is it Polish again and furthermore, is $(X\setminus A)\setminus B$ also Polish?

Translated in $X=\mathbb{R}$, choose $A=(0,1)$, so $X\setminus A=(-\infty, 0]\cup[1, \infty)$, then  $B=[1,2)$ is again open in $X\setminus A$ and thus Polish as well as $(X\setminus A)\setminus B =(-\infty, 0]\cup[2, \infty)$.

But does this hold in general, that is, for $A_1, A_2\subset X$ open, does it always hold that $A_1\setminus A_2$  is Polish?

I have tried to show that it is a $G_\delta$ set but I was not so successful with it

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes. Just mentally replace $X\setminus A$ with $X$: once you’ve established that $X\setminus A$ is Polish, it remains true that any open subset of it is a Polish subspace.

Comment: Yes, I also thought so, but then, if I accept that as true, it follows that any Borel subset of X is a Polish space. Or am I mistaken somewhere?

Comment: @math_as_a_lifestyle Whether or not your conclusion is true, I'm not sure, but I don't see a simple proof using this idea. Notice that open subsets of $A$ if $A$ is closed in $X$ don't need to also be open in $X$, etc., so there are problems there, and also this argumentation can only work with finite induction. In fact, I know your conclusion is *false* because $\Bbb Q$ is a Borel subset of the Polish space $\Bbb R$ yet $\Bbb Q$ is famously not Polish

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to understand. $[1,2)$ is neither open not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, but is is Polish subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (because it is $G_\delta$ subset). However, it is also  Polish in $(-\infty,0]\cup[1, \infty)$ since it is open in this space. So my question is: is this an accident or holds in general? That is, if $C$ is Polish in subspace topology, is it always Polish in topology on whole space $X$. And yes $\mathbb{Q}$ is a good counterexample.

Comment: @math_as_a_lifestyle The property of being Polish is "absolute": it is irrelevant what the ambient space is. A Polish space is just a Polish space, be it contained in $\Bbb R$ or anything else. $[1,2)$ is a Polish space. If $X$ is a topological space containing $[1,2)$ as a subspace, great, that does not change the fact that $[1,2)$ is Polish

Comment: But being Polish depends on the reference topology. So for example $(0,1)$ with metric from $\mathbb{R}$ is not complete, however, we can construct a metric that generates the topology compatible with the Euclidean topology such that $(0,1)$ is complete, and in particular Polish. So, maybe my question is very stupid, but it is not clear to be how to show that for example, $A_1\setminus A_2$ (given in the question) is a $G_\delta$ subset of $X$.

Comment: @math_as_a_lifestyle Being Polish does **not** depend on the topology of the ambient space

Comment: A space is Polish if and only if it is separable and there exists an admissible metric under which it is complete. That is agnostic of, say, whether or not the space is a subspace of $\Bbb R$. $(0,1)$ is Polish. Yes, the subspace metric is not going to completely metrise $(0,1)$, but, that has nothing to do with whether or not $(0,1)$ is Polish since there are other metrics that foot the bill. I think you're confusing "subspace which is Polish" with "a *complete* subspace under the subspace metric", these are two different things. Only closed subsets are complete under the subspace metric.